# SFTP for 2 different accounts in Ubuntu Server 14.10

Tags: server, 14.10, webserver, sftp

I would like to ask how to make 2 different accounts for an SFTP login with my dedicated server (Ubuntu Server 14.10).

The two account: A1 and A2 are the example names.

After the Apache server (an the must have for a web server, sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ php5-gd libssh2-php), my necessity is to make different login from SFTP for different website (the web server host 10 different website)

The problem is that i would like to access with A1 to /var/www/html/ and i ever can browse the parent folders.

With A2 i would like to access only in one subfolder of html (/var/www/html/subfolder/).

The parent folders browsing must be disable for the second SFTP account.

I try many solutions but anythings are the good way.

Thank You very very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can give A2 execute permission to `/var/www/html`, this lets him `cd` or use a SFTP client to open the folder, but without read or write permissions, he cannot edit any files, or even list the folder's contents.

To accomplish this, firstly give A1 read/write/execute permission, and other/public (anyone who can log into the system). Because by default, root owns the `/var/www/html`, so we need to set the folder's group to A1, and set the permissions

```
sudo chgrp A1 /var/www/html
sudo chmod 771 /var/www/html
```

This allows anyone to go into the /var/www/html, but not edit or view the content folders. You can enter sub directories if you know their name, and have execute permissions. Next we should create a folder for A2. Set A2 as the owner of the folder, and set A1 as group and give him/her full permissions.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/subfolder
sudo chown A2:A1 /var/www/html/subfolder
sudo chmod 771 /var/www/html/subfolder
```

Now only A1 can list and edit the files inside `/var/www/html`, but A2 has permission to go into `/var/www/html/subfolder`, because (1) he has the execute bit, and (2) he knows it exists.

Comment: Hi @Henry and thank You very much!  So A1 is a group and A2 is the name of the second account...right? If i would like to add an another account sftp (we call this user A3) for a second subfolder of html (/var/www/html/subfolder2/), I will make: sudo mkdir /var/www/html/subfolder2 sudo chown A3:A1 /var/www/html/subfolder2/ sudo chmod 771 /var/www/html/subfolder2/...right?

Comment: Yes, A1 is you (or the user that can access all the `/var/www/html`, and all it's subdirectories), A1 is also your group. By default Ubuntu creates a group for everyuser, so by setting the group of the folder to your group, and apply permissions, you get access to the folder without letting others in, or being the owner.

Comment: Thank You so much @Henry! sorry for the late in the answer! You are a great!